# How to install programs from salvaged Ubuntu drive

Tags: software-installation

My laptop was ruined in the Zadar flash flood on Tuesday, but the internal drive survived intact.  The OS was Ubuntu 14.04.

I managed after 8 hours of sweat to dual install Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 on a new laptop, and migrated my Thunderbird and Mozilla files, all working now.

How do I now reinstall all my old programs on the new installation?  Is it just a matter of copying over the directories above my home directory?

Thanks in advance!

More details: 
`sudo parted -l` gives the following with the old internal drive mounted in the USB port:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      525MB   108GB   107GB   primary   ntfs
 3      108GB   109GB   888MB   primary   ntfs            diag
 4      109GB   1000GB  891GB   extended
 5      109GB   992GB   883GB   logical   ext4
 6      992GB   1000GB  8474MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: JMicron  (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  992GB   992GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      992GB   1000GB  8454MB  extended
 5      992GB   1000GB  8454MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)`
```

And the drive in question is the `JMicron`.  In Nautilus the disk is listed as `992 GB Volume` and when I open this disk, the name above the folder is `4619c393-d2d3-4999-a09a-98def8d8ba3e`. In Gparted it is listed as `/dev/sdb1  ext4` with `/dev/sdb2 extended` and `/dev/sdb5 linux-swap`.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/137991/367990

Answer (score 0):

Under no circumstances should you think of "copying over the directories above my home directory". Some of the directories like `proc` and `dev` are very special mounts.

- Connect the external drive say under `mnt`.
- `chroot /mnt`
- `dpkg -l`

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh!  I'm not sure I understand your answer -- I've added some details in the OP.  What on my drive system corresponds to `/mnt` in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I accomplished the above, following @Kaveh's advice:

1. `sudo chroot /media/myname/4619c393-d2d3-4999-a09a-98def8d8ba3e`.
2. `dpkg -l > /home/myname/Desktop/allpacks`

This put a list of packages installed on my previous drive into the above file.  Now I can decide which ones I want installed, leave them in the file, and use dpkg again to install the desired ones on my new system, as described in the link [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages/137991#137991) provided by @ByteCommander.